# Error when attempting to use new com.android.test plugin in project with flavors

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

We have a project which is using flavors and want to use the new com.android.test plugin available with gradle 1.3 to have our integration tests in a separate project.   We've followed the instructions [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/studio/studio-features.html#test-module), but when we try to sync gradle we get the following error:

> Error:Configuration with name 'MyFlavorDebug-classes' not found.

Here is our test project's build.gradle file.  We have a matching flavor in our app.

```
buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }

}

apply plugin: 'com.android.test'


android {

    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion = '22.0.1'
    targetProjectPath ':MyApp'
    targetVariant 'MyFlavorDebug'
}
```

Comment: Adding "publishNonDefault true" to the build.gradle was the key.

Answer (score 2):

You should have a structure like this:

```
root
 app 
   build.gradle
 flavor1test
   build.gradle
```

In `app/build.gradle`

```
   android{
       defaultConfig {
           applicationId 'com.example.myapp'

       }
       productFlavors {
            flavor1 {
               //   
            }
       }
    }
```

In  `flavor1test/build.gradle` something like:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.test' // A plugin used for test-only-modules

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion = '23.0.0rc3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion XX
        targetSdkVersion 22

        // The package name of the test app
        testApplicationId 'com.example.myapp'

     // The Instrumentation test runner used to run tests.
        testInstrumentationRunner 'android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
    }

    // Set the target app project.
    targetProjectPath ':app'
    targetVariant 'flavor1Debug'
}

dependencies {
    // Android Testing Support Library's runner and rules and hamcrest matchers
}
```